# data field in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

If I have the following code with me inside the data: section of $.ajax call of jQuery :

```
data : {

     INPDESC : $("#AddContent #inpDesc").val(),
                DefaultID: $('#DefaulID').val() 


            },
```

Basically, #AddContent is the id field of the div tag like the following :

```
<div id='AddContent' class="someclass">
```

and #DefaultID is the id defined inside the above div tag in the cfinput tag as follows:

```
<cfinput type="text" name="DefaultID" id="DefaultID" value="4" />
```

Similarly, #inpDesc is and id of  another input field of type text.

My questions is, what is the need to pass the #AddContent id, can't it be just #inpDesc id in place of both because AddContent id is just defining the layout ?

I mean can't it be like the following:

```
data : {

     INPDESC : $("#inpDesc").val(),
                DefaultID: $('#DefaulID').val() 


            },
```

Comment: If you know JavaScript you don't need to use cfinput.

Comment: I am not proficient in it. Could you provide an example of what you are saying?

Comment: It can be quite challenging to do ajax and use the jQuery library without being  proficient in JavaScript. It is kind of like learning to run before learning to walk. Also `<cfinput>` is not going to help you in the short term, or the long term.

Comment: Try writing your code without `cfform`/`cfinput` and use just plain `form`/`input` instead. `cfinput` does a lot of things you don't need (such as adding an `ID` automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ID's **must** be unique on each page, so there's no need to use both ID's in the selector.